# Объяснение кода: убрать расширение php в конце url

Tags: .htaccess

Объясните, пожалуйста, код. А если есть ошибки, то исправьте. Этот код для того чтоб в конце `url` убиралось расширение `php`. Да кстати, ещё скажите как добавлять сайты для убирания расширения.

**.htaccess**

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}\.php -f
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ $1.php
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

```
RewriteEngine on //Запускаем движок замены
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d //если запрашиваемый объект не папка
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}\.php -f //если запрашиваемый объект с дописанным расширением php - файл
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ $1.php //делаем замену с дописыванием .php
```

В этом коде неправильно сделаны комментарии, поэтому он и не работает.
Комментарии должны писаться отдельной строкой до каждой инструкции и перед ними должен ставится знак `#`.
Правильно нужно делать так:

```
 # Запускаем движок замены

RewriteEngine on

 # Если запрашиваемый объект не папка

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d

 # если запрашиваемый объект с дописанным расширением php - файл

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}\.php -f

 # делаем замену с дописыванием .php

RewriteRule ^(.*)$ $1.php
```

В этом случае, инструкции будут работать вместе с комментариями.

Answer (score 2):

```
RewriteEngine on //Запускаем движок замены
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d //если запрашиваемый объект не папка
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}\.php -f //если запрашиваемый объект с дописанным расширением php - файл
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ $1.php //делаем замену с дописыванием .php
```

Comment: 1.php - это тот самый файл в котором будет убираться расширение? Если да, то напишите как добавить ещё одну страницу

Comment: не 1.php, а $1.php. Доллар означает, что берем первую переменную из регулярки, которая соответствует первым скобкам.

Comment: Дак то есть если я этот код вставлю без изменений, прям как здесь написано, то на каждой странице будет уже отображаться без расширения? Если да, то у меня высвечивается ошибка, что нету такой страницы(в конце ссылки просто убираю расширение). А если просто на страницу захожу, то расширение не убирается.

Answer (score 2):

**.htaccess**

```
AddDefaultCharset UTF-8

RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule ^([^.?]+)$ %{REQUEST_URI}.php [L]
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} "^[^ ]* .*?\.php[? ].*$"
RewriteRule .* - [L,R=404]
```

**index.php**

```
<a href="php/info>info</a>
```

Файлы оставь с расширением ПХП, а в ссылках удаляй это расширение...

Comment: Пожалуйста, постарайтесь писать более развернутые ответы. Уверен, автор вопроса был бы благодарен за ваш экспертный комментарий к приведенному выше коду.

Answer (score 0):

Я не могу объяснить работу вашего кода, но могу дать вам более короткое решение, данной задачи.

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^(\w+)$ $1.php [NC]
```

Answer (score 0):

**Файл:** `.htaccess`

---

```
# Запускаем движок замены
RewriteEngine 
# Если запрашиваемый объект не папка
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
# Если запрашиваемый объект с расширением php - файл
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}\.php -f
# Делаем замену с дописыванием ".php"
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ $1.php
```