# Стоит ли убирать расширение из адресной строки?

Tags: php, html

Прочитал несколько статей и ответов на другие вопросы (включая [этот](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/231838/%D0%9E%D0%B1%D1%8A%D1%8F%D1%81%D0%BD%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5-%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%B4%D0%B0-%D1%83%D0%B1%D1%80%D0%B0%D1%82%D1%8C-%D1%80%D0%B0%D1%81%D1%88%D0%B8%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5-php-%D0%B2-%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%BD%D1%86%D0%B5-url)) на тему того, нужно как убрать расширение файла (`.html`, `.php`) из адресной строки. Теперь вопрос: а стоит ли стремиться это делать?

С точки зрения посетителей сайта, расширение файла видеть в строке абсолютно ни к чему. Что насчёт технической стороны?

Comment: Наоборот нужно подставлять какое-то совершенно левое расширение, чтобы всех запутать. Ставить asp вместо php, Пусть думают, что сайт работает на asp.net

Comment: Пользователи, далёкие от веб-технологий (каких большинство), вообще про php и не слышали.

Answer (score 1):

Рекомендую почитать [w3](https://www.w3.org/Provider/Style/URI.html).

Во многих случаях можно убирать расширение. Скажем, если вам нужна ссылка на страницу, то я бы рекомендовал убирать, например `http://example.org/first/`.

Но для контента рекомендовал бы оставлять. Скажем, если на странице `http://example.org/first/` у нас есть видео, то ссылку лучше делать такой `http://example.org/first/coolVideo.mp4`, а не `http://example.org/first/coolVideo`.

Расширение так же позволяет браузеру понять, что за контент перед ним. Скажем, если предоставляете ссылку на Excel документ, к примеру, то лучше добавлять расширение `http://example.org/first/myExcel.xls`. Тогда браузер при закачке предоставит выбор, чем открыть этот документ после скачки. Умные браузеры, вероятно, и без расширения это могут определить, но не все.

Так же, некоторые рекомендуют скрывать расширения, так как это усложняет процесс взлома.

Если используете CDN, то расширение тоже весьма полезно.

Comment: Расширение не обязательно, определяется тип прекрасно по Content-Type заголовку (даже в первую очередь по заголовку, а потом уже расширение). Но действительно смысла в этом не очень много. Единственное когда понадобилось, делать приватные фото, как например в вк (с правами доступа), в остальном оставляю, т.к. для того что бы убрать расширение нужно использовать `routing` как минимум, что накладывает дополнительные расходы, вместо того что-бы nginx-ом дешево раздавать статику.

Comment: Расширение не нужно, потому что есть mime-типы.

Comment: @higimo я бы яички отрезал разработчикам, которые убирают расширения у контент файлов. Я как юзер хочу, открывая ссылку/файл, видеть, что это за тип и т.п.

Comment: @Suvitruf отрезайте и правильно сделаете. Мы тут про скрипты говорим, если что. Контент-тайма и мим-типов для опознавания контента хватит.