# Расширение html или php в адресной строке браузера?

Tags: веб-программирование, браузер, localhost

Как возможно убрать расширение html или php в адресной строке, в случае если сайт пишется без cms; есть ли у кого проверенные рабочие решения? Вопрос с того, что пару решений из сети не дали нужного результата(проблему пытался решить на localhost openserver).

Comment: Добрый день. https://encrypted.google.com/search?q=%D0%9A%D0%B0%D0%BA+%D0%B2%D0%BE%D0%B7%D0%BC%D0%BE%D0%B6%D0%BD%D0%BE+%D1%83%D0%B1%D1%80%D0%B0%D1%82%D1%8C+%D1%80%D0%B0%D1%81%D1%88%D0%B8%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5+html+%D0%B8%D0%BB%D0%B8+php+%D0%B2+%D0%B0%D0%B4%D1%80%D0%B5%D1%81%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%B9+%D1%81%D1%82%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%BA%D0%B5

Comment: *пишется без cms* - без rewrite rules ?

Comment: Возможный дубликат вопроса: [Объяснение кода: убрать расширение php в конце url](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/231838/%d0%9e%d0%b1%d1%8a%d1%8f%d1%81%d0%bd%d0%b5%d0%bd%d0%b8%d0%b5-%d0%ba%d0%be%d0%b4%d0%b0-%d1%83%d0%b1%d1%80%d0%b0%d1%82%d1%8c-%d1%80%d0%b0%d1%81%d1%88%d0%b8%d1%80%d0%b5%d0%bd%d0%b8%d0%b5-php-%d0%b2-%d0%ba%d0%be%d0%bd%d1%86%d0%b5-url)

Comment: rewrite rules — у меня лишь отдалённое понимание термина, то есть здесь я реально стучу по дереву. Просто пишу статичный сайт на 4  страницы, с небольшим объёмом контента; не вижу необходимости в cms, хотя могу сделать на modx.

Comment: Делаешь файловую структуру такого вида `root/index.html`, `root/about/index.html`, `root/contact/index.html`. А в страницах ссылки `<a href="/contact/">Контакты</a>`. Браузер автоматом будет открывать index.html файл из папки. В URL будет выглядешь как `site.ru/contact`

Comment: Есть такое мнение — mod_rewrite для Apache или location для nginx. Правильно ли понимаю, что если реальный сервер на nginix, то mod_rewrite не сработает и наоборот?

Comment: "Делаешь файловую структуру такого вида root/index.html" — если это единственное возможно решение, то — грусть, печаль.