# Как поменять название каталога сайта?

Tags: javascript, html, css, веб-программирование

Есть сайт, допустим mywebsite.com (index.html), хочу сделать переход на другую страницу (second.html). Как сделать так, чтобы страница называлась mywebsite.com/second/, а не mywebsite.com/second.html?

Comment: Нужно настраивать .htaccess

Comment: Возможный дубликат вопроса: [Объяснение кода: убрать расширение php в конце url](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/231838/%d0%9e%d0%b1%d1%8a%d1%8f%d1%81%d0%bd%d0%b5%d0%bd%d0%b8%d0%b5-%d0%ba%d0%be%d0%b4%d0%b0-%d1%83%d0%b1%d1%80%d0%b0%d1%82%d1%8c-%d1%80%d0%b0%d1%81%d1%88%d0%b8%d1%80%d0%b5%d0%bd%d0%b8%d0%b5-php-%d0%b2-%d0%ba%d0%be%d0%bd%d1%86%d0%b5-url)

Answer (score 0):

Знак **/** в конце урл-а означает, что он заканчивается именем каталога, а не файла. Если в этом каталоге будет файл **index.html**, то он будет открываться, когда в браузере будут набирать такой адрес: **mywebsite.com/second/**. Или даже: **mywebsite.com/second** Т. е., это то же самое, что набирать **mywebsite.com/second/index.html**